# Enabling/Disabling Visual Studio Qt plugin per solution

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to work on two customer projects, one of which uses the $(QTDIR) definition introduced by Digia's Qt add-in.

When the add-in is installed, I cannot build any solution that doesn't use the Qt plugin because "no Qt version is set for this project".

Is there a way to disable the Qt add-in per-solution so it doesn't interfere with the build process in non-Qt projects?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, not yet. I have set up a second computer.

Comment: In VS 2013 I can't even disable Qt Addon completely... after restarting VS it will be active again...